How to remove the accessibility item from the userbar
Is there a way to remove the accessibility item from the Wagtail userbar?

In myapp/wagtail_hooks.py add:
from wagtail.core import hooks
from wagtail.admin.userbar import AccessibilityItem

@hooks.register('construct_wagtail_userbar')
def remove_userbar_accessibility_item(request, items):
    items[:] = [item for item in items if not isinstance(item, AccessibilityItem)]

